# How to access geth from nodejs

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

I have geth running on localhost:

```
geth.exe --testnet --fast --cache 1024 --ipcpath \\.\pipe\geth.ipc --rpccorsdomain * --rpcport 8545 --rpc
```

If I do the following:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
var abi = ...
web3.eth.Contract(abi,"0x5cb023C894D7838Ee7C0eE43AFD8D10D75Cd89bd");
```

This gives me an error: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: currentProvider on the last line, error happens inside web3-core\src\index.js:42:16

Second syntax, which one can find on the net:

```
web3.eth.contract(abi)
```

gives another error: TypeError: web3.eth.contract is not a function

What is the right syntax to execute contract from nodejs with geth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your web3 version with,

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.version
```

If you get `1.0.0-beta.11` or similar (rather than `0.20.0`) then you've picked up the new version. `npm` now installs the new version by default.

You can either go back to the older version with `npm install web3@0.20.0`, or consult the [documentation](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/index.html) for the new version for all the (many, many) changes.

This should answer your specific question with the new syntax:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x.....');
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-eth

```
// install using yarn or npm
npm install web3
yarn add web3
```

```
// in node.js
var Web3Eth = require('web3-eth'),
   eth = new Web3Eth('ws://localhost:8546');
```